# Renaming the "I'm having this problem too" Low Quality flag reason

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

When voting on the Low Quality Queue, you can see this deletion reason::

[image]

This is more of a reason suited to Stack Overflow. Perhaps we could change it?

Comment: Do have a suggestion as to what you want instead?

Comment: I don't unfortunately, holroy, or I would've included it <_<

Comment: Probably something along the lines of a user just posting to ask for a review of their program that performs a similar goal.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

> This is a request to review a different solution to a similar problem, it does not actually review the code that has been posted in the question. If you'd like a review of your code, you can ask for one by clicking [Ask Question].

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be a request. I agree with what you're trying to do here, but I think the wording can be improved.

Comment: @Mast That's a good point. Maybe more towards "This answer discusses a different solution"? Something that acknowledges that they're focused on their implementation even if it's not actually asking for a review. The challenge is avoiding implying that they can't bring up a different implementation if it's relevant to their review.

Answer (score 1):

#### Do we need this?

I'd say we do **not** need this case. I mean come on, how often does it happen someone posts their own code for review into an answer?

This isn't even remotely enough often as that such a thing would make sense...

Looking at the recent deletions in the 10k tools, the only answers deleted were deleted by mods. I didn't check, (because the UI makes it kinda hard), but I think none of these deletions were for this specific problem.

I guess that most of this is converting to comments and cleaning up code-only answers, but maybe a mod can provide numbers on this.

Don't try to optimize things that happen once every leap year :)